# How to get custom post type menu_name?

Tags: custom-post-types, menus

I'd like to show the post type of a post, you can do that with [get_post_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type), but in my case the names are not pretty (for ex : p_project_plans). So instead I thought I'd show the asociated "menu_name" (as declared with register_post_type), which looks much nicer (for ex : Project plans).

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi **@mike23:**

This code shows you how to get both singular and plural names *(assuming you specified them as such in your `register_post_type()`)*.

Note that the code example is presented as a standalone file you can save as `test.php` file in the root of your website and load in your browser with `http://yoursite.com/test.php` *(assuming you replace `yoursite.com` with your site's domain!):*

```
<?php
/*
Filename: test.php
*/
include( '../wp-load.php' );
header( 'Content-type:text/plain' );

$post_type_object = get_post_type_object('p_project_plans');

echo "Singular: {$post_type_object->labels->singular_name}\n";
echo "Plural: {$post_type_object->labels->name}\n";
```

Comment: @mike23 - Glad I could help!

Comment: 'name' and 'singular_name' != 'menu_name''.

Comment: @MichaelRogers True, `name` and `singular_name` are not equal to menu name, but menu name is assigned the value of `name`. It can be overridden, but by default menu name is effectively equal to `name`. Further, given the OP's request was for a _"pretty"_ name for a post type, and `$post_type_object->labels->name` certainly qualifies for that, and probably moreso than menu name.

Comment: Your answer helped me get the menu_name which is what i needed so thanks!